# I've used jquery to access innerHTML of list items but it returns Undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angular

I am creating this grocery list application with Angular4, so I need the user to be able to click on an item and it will be added to the bookmarked section.
I used Jquery to access the innerHTML of the li when we hover over it, take the value and add it into the bookmark array, but the innerHTML keeps returning "undefined".

javascript:I used this bit to get the innerHTML

```
$('li').hover(function(){
  console.log($(this).innerHTML);
});
```

html:I've used *ngfor to spit out all the list items

```
<div class="col-m-6">
    <h3 class="text-primary">All Items</h3>
    <ol>
        <li class="listItem" *ngFor="let g of groceries">{{g}}</li>
    </ol>
</div>
```

In the console it keeps showing "undefined", please help. TIA

Comment: its `undefined` since `innerHTML` is a property of HTML Elements and `$(this)` is a jquery object wrapping the HTML elements. Either try with jquery methods `.html()` of `.text()` or to first get the HTML element from jquery object `$(this)[0].innerHTML` or simply `this.innerHTML`

Comment: As somebody that has to maintain an Angular project with a lot of jQuery I recommend you to to use @tchelidze answer and avoid jQuery completely. Angular does not always know when jQuery changes something and as your application grows it is a nightmare to debug and fix errors.

Answer (score 2):

**Avoid** using Jquery or any other way of direct DOM manipulation while developing SPA.

Try following

*Template*

```
 <li class="listItem" *ngFor="let g of groceries" (click)="onClick(g.id)">      
    {{g}}
 </li>
```

*Component*

```
onClick(id) { 
   //add to bookmark
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Solution1:**  Use `html()` jQuery.

***Stack Snippet***

```js
$('li').hover(function(){
  console.log($(this).html());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-m-6">
  <h3 class="text-primary">All Items</h3>
  <ol>
    <li class="listItem" *ngFor="let g of groceries">{{g}}</li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

**Solution2:**  Use `this.innerHTML`.

***Stack Snippet***

```js
$('li').hover(function(){
  console.log(this.innerHTML);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-m-6">
  <h3 class="text-primary">All Items</h3>
  <ol>
    <li class="listItem" *ngFor="let g of groceries">{{g}}</li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you have need to use jQuery html() method to gett innerHTML. 
So, use the following:

```js
$('li').hover(function(){
  console.log($(this).html());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-m-6">
    <h3 class="text-primary">All Items</h3>
    <ol>
        <li class="listItem" *ngFor="let g of groceries">{{g}}</li>
    </ol>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

For jQuery to work on dynamic elements you should be doing it this way

```
$(document).on('hover', 'li', function(){
    console.log($(this).innerHTML);
});
```